# Compute the integral $\int_S \operatorname{curl}(F)\cdot n\ dS$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $S$ be the upper hemisphere of radius $r>0$ centered at the origin in $\mathbb R^3$. Let $F:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ $$F(x,y,z)=(xy^2\tanh(x^2+z),x+y^4e^{-x^2}\sin z,x^2(x^2+3)ye^{-x^2-y^2-z^2})$$
Compute $$\int_S \operatorname{curl}(F) \cdot n \ dS$$ where $n$ is the outward unit normal.

What is the most reasonable way to compute this integral? Am I supposed to compute $\operatorname{curl}(F)$ and the normal? Are there simplifications enabling one to make the computation of $\operatorname{curl}(F)$ easier? (Otherwise it seems too much work). Am I supposed to apply Stoke's theorem maybe?

Comment: You can use the divergence theorem.
$$\int_S (A\cdot n) dS = \int_{V} \text{div}(A) dV$$
(where $S=\partial V$)
and then some vector identities.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz So is the integral zero then? Because div of curl of $F$ is zero if the components of $F$ are $C^2$.

Comment: If by "hemisphere" you mean the upper cap AND the disk, then yes because the surface is closed. Else, if you just mean the cap, you can take the disk that closes the surface and the integrals over the cap and over the disk will be negatives of each other. Then the integral over the disk may (or may not) be easier to evaluate. I've not really made the calculation

Comment: Other possibility is to go to spherical coordinates. I'm not really sure, but $F$ seems to be simpler there.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Why does the integration region matter if the integral is taken of the zero function? I thought any integral over any region of the zero function is zero.

Comment: In the divergence theorem, the RHS is only equal to the LHS if $S$ is a closed surface, then $V$ is the volume enclosed by $S$.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I see, thanks. By $S$ I mean $\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\text{ and } z\ge 0\}$, so the divergence theorem is applicable and the integral is zero. Edit: oops, I guess it's not.

Comment: That's not a closed surface! It won't work. In this case the divergence theorem just tells you that the integral is the negative of the integral over the disk of radius $r$ on the $xy$ plane.

Comment: (+1) for suggesting Stokes' theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Stokes' theorem the integral is

$$I =\int_S \text{curl } \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \,dS = \oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d \,\mathbf{l} $$

where $C$ is the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin of the $xy-$plane.

On $C$ we have, using polar coordinates,  $F_x = xy^2 \tanh(x^2) = r^3\cos \theta\sin^2 \theta \tanh(r^2 \cos^2 \theta)$ and $F_y = x = r \cos \theta$.  The unit tangent to $C$ is $- \sin \theta \, \mathbf{e}_x + \cos \theta \, \mathbf{e}_y$, with no $z-$component. Consequently,

$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} r^3\cos\theta \sin^2 \theta \tanh(r^2 \cos^2 \theta) (-\sin \theta) r \, d \theta + \int_0^{2 \pi}r \cos \theta  (\cos \theta) r\,d \theta \\ = -r^4  \underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\cos \theta \sin^3 \theta \tanh(r^2\cos^2 \theta) \, d \theta}_{= \,0 \text{ by symmetry}} \, + \,r^2\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2 \theta \, d \theta \\ = \pi r^2$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify how exactly you used symmetry? This came up in my earlier question too, but I'm still not sure how to use symmetry when the integration is over something like $[0,2\pi]$. I know that the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval $[-r,r]$ is zero. In this case the integrand is odd, but the interval is not symmetric.

Comment: The integrals over $[0,\pi/2]$ and $[\pi/2,\pi]$ cancel.  Similarly the integrals over $[\pi,3\pi/2]$ and $[3\pi/2,2\pi]$  cancel.   A graph shows the function has the same symmetric shape over each of those intervals (vanishing at the end points) with signs +, - , +, -

Comment: Why doesn't Stokes' theorem contradict to the Divergence theorem here? As discussed in the comments above, the integral in question is the negative of the integral over the circle in the $xy$-plane; but by Stokes' theorem it's the positive of that integral.

Comment: Stokes' theorem says the surface integral of the curl of $F$ over the hemisphere is the line integral of $F$ around the circle in a counterclockwise sense. The divergence theorem says the integral over the hemisphere is the negative of the surface integral of the curl of $F$ over the disk (with normal vector pointing in the negative $z$ direction). Another application of Stokes' theorem equates this with the line integral around the circle.